# Ruby on Rails - Bulk insert of data with logging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, activerecord, redis, bulkinsert

My application is an analytics application and gets real-time data each second from several sites and all these are added inside the `insights` table.

Currently, each data request is sent to `log_insight` action and added to a log file as such:

```
class Insight < ApplicationRecord
  def self.write_log(log_file, log_line)
    File.open(log_file, "a") { |file| file.puts (log_line.gsub("\n", " ")) }
  end
end

class InsightsController < ApplicationController
  def log_insight
    Insight.write_log('log/insights.log', data.to_json)
  end
end
```

And every 30 minutes, these logs are added to the `insights` table *(I'm using `Activerecord-Import` gem)* and a new `insights.log` is being created, and the process continues.

*PS: Throughout the day there are around a million records being processed and added to the `insights` table.*

I feel this is not the efficient or *right* way to go with.

One suggestion that I've been thinking of was to use `redis` and write the logs in the memory and every 30 minutes take out everything and do a `flush`.

```
Rails 6.1.4
Ruby 2.5.8
Redis 4.4
```

Any suggestion is much appreciated!

Comment: Is adding to the `insights` table directly not an option? A million records is not that much in 24 hours.

Comment: No becuase that would be a bad practice for the db as it needs to open and close a l of times